# Filtering list of tibbles based on a particular value in a tibble

Tags: r

I have a list of tibbles. I want to filter it and get a new list, where value from the first column is equal to a particular value.

```
library(tidyverse)
mylist <- list(tibble(x = 1:5),tibble(x = 6:10),tibble(x = 11:15))
```

For example, from the list above I would like to get a list, of tibbles, where only 3 is presented. In my real example it would be not a number, but a case-sensitive string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `lapply` and `filter`

```
lapply(mylist, function(df){
  df %>%
    filter(x == 3)
})

[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
      x
  <int>
1     3

[[2]]
# A tibble: 0 x 1
# ... with 1 variable: x <int>

[[3]]
# A tibble: 0 x 1
# ... with 1 variable: x <int>
```